# ELMAH with 3 Tier Architecture: How to pass context to middle tier

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, elmah, 3-tier

We've built a new website using Microsoft asp.net Web API 2.
The front end has no database connections, therefore ELMAH is installed on the middleware layer.  The middleware is logging fine to ELMAH and we have a logging class we can call to log caught exceptions as well.  The problem I am having is how to get the front end to properly log errors.  Right now we are passing the exception through Web API to the middleware, but ELMAH also needs the HttpContext.  I know I can log without it, but it makes debugging quite difficult.  I really want to pass the context along as well but just can't figure out how.  The HttpContext does not serialize to JSON properly.  I've tried just sending the Server Variables and Headers from the request but I can't seem to create a new HttpRequest and add those to it (keep getting the old "Operation is not supported on this platform" error).

So my question is, how do I properly get the context from the front end to the middelware server so I can log it with ELMAH?

Comment: I'd log website-frontend errors locally only. Especially when the frontend is a presentation layer only. There's Little use in trying to send the backend an exception like "the Server did not respond" - it probably already knows that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your tiers? Is the frontend C# code running inside IIS as well?